# gravar hora no banco Postgresql

Tags: php, html5, postgresql

Na aplicação eu informo a hora de inicio e fim da atividade, e guardo essa informação no banco.

Segue Query:

```
$status = $_GET['status'];
$intervalo = $_GET['intervalo'];
$dataini = $_GET['horainicio']."<br>";
$horainicio = date('H:i:s',$dataini);
$datafim = $_GET['horafinal']."<br>";
$horafinal = date('H:i:s',$datafim);
$qtdtentativas = $_GET['qtdtentativas'];
$destino = $_GET['destino'];
$skill = $_GET['skill'];
$pacing = $_GET['pacing'];
$prefixo = $_GET['prefixo'];



$query = sprintf("update bettaivr.public.ivr_campanha set status = %d,horainicio = %d,horafinal = %d, intervalo = %d, pacing = %d, qtdtentativas = %d  where id = %s",
$status,$horainicio ,$horafinal ,$intervalo, $pacing, $qtdtentativas,$campanha);
```

Entretanto não consigo guardar os horarios no banco, ele retorna 0 sempre.
Como posso guardar esse horario no banco?

Erro sinalizado ao executar a query:

Problem with query update bettaivr.public.ivr_campanha set status = 0,horainicio = '0',horafinal = '0', intervalo = 20, pacing = 1, qtdtentativas = 5 where id = 4

Comment: Qual o tipo de dado que esta no campo de horas do banco de dados?

Comment: esta como time no banco.

Comment: os campos de hora estão entre apostrofos??

Comment: no banco não. na aplicação estão desse jeito como demonstrado, adicionei a resposta que vem do banco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema está aqui:

```
$horafinal = date('H:i:s',$datafim);
$horainicio = date('H:i:s',$dataini);
```

tenta assim:

```
$horafinal = date('H:i:s',strtotime($datafim));
$horainicio = date('H:i:s',strtotime($dataini));
```

E usa a query dessa forma:

```
$query = "
    UPDATE 
        bettaivr.public.ivr_campanha 
    SET 
        status = '$status',
        horainicio = '$horainicio',
        horafinal = '$horafinal',
        intervalo = '$intervalo',
        pacing = '$pacing',
        qtdtentativas = '$qtdtentativas'
    WHERE id = '$campanha'
";
```

- Algumas referências da documentação sobre `date` e `strtotime`:

> [strtotime — Interpreta qualquer descrição de data/hora em texto em inglês em timestamp Unix](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php)
>
> [date — Formata a data e a hora local. Retorna uma string de acordo com a string de formato informada usando o inteiro timestamp informado](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php)

Comment: Ainda não resolveu, o problema persistiu. 
ele devolveu este erro 
ERROR: column "horainicio" is of type time without time zone but expression is of type integer LINE 1: ...r.public.ivr_campanha set status = 0,horainicio = 0,horafina... ^ HINT: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Comment: quando eu escrevo para o banco: 
sprintf("update bettaivr.public.ivr_campanha set status = %d, horainicio = %i ,horafinal = %i, intervalo = %d, pacing = %d, qtdtentativas = %d  where id = %s",
  $status,$horainicio ,$horafinal ,$intervalo, $pacing, $qtdtentativas,$campanha);
acho que o formato da escrita pode estar errado, mas não acho o certo

Comment: Editei a resposta, tenta ai pra ver, usando o que eu falei tbm sobre as variaveis de hora, já que o erro acusa que o valor esta sendo passado em tipo int

Comment: Show cara, ja começou a dar outra cara para a query, agora o erro é de variavel que recebe.. 
ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "08:00:00" LINE 9: pacing = '08:00:00', ^

vou olhar como esta recebendo esses valores

Comment: Ele esta indicando erro de integer, falando que o tipo é int, verifica isso

Comment: o erro que ele deu, foi que o campo pacing não deve receber a hora, por algum  motivo quando eu faço o get ele pega os dados do dataini, mas ta dando certo.